# How to set recycler view item to half the screen width using constraint layout?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a grid recycler view where the row has 2 items . I want to know , how can i set the recycler view item to half the screen size using constraint layout so that the item fits perfectly to the grid recycler view's row. Any help would be much appreciated.

The Holder.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/shoeimage"
                />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/doris_bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Nike Air Max 97 EOI " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:fontFamily="@font/doris_extra_bold"
            android:text="Rs 16,595" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: how about using dynamic width for your parent view?

Comment: please share your Holder.xml

Comment: Try `new GridLayoutManager(this, 2)` , 2 number signifies the items count in row